# Smarty replace multiple values that can contain eachother

Tags: replace, smarty

In my smarty template I got color-codes from my DB like this:

`c#m#fc#fm#`

Now I want to replace each color-code with a html tag.

`c# => <i class='fas fa-circle cyan'></i>
m# => <i class='fas fa-circle magenta'></i>
fc# => <i class='fas fa-circle lightmagenta'></i>
fm# => <i class='fas fa-circle lightcyan'></i>`

I tried it this way:

`[{$oAttr->oxattribute__oxvalue->value|replace:"c#":"<i class='fas fa-circle cyan'></i>"|replace:"m#":"<i class='fas fa-circle magenta'></i>"|replace:"fc#":"<i class='fas fa-circle fcyan'></i>"|replace:"fm#":"<i class='fas fa-circle fmagenta'></i>"}]`

The problem is that `replace:"c#":"<i class='fas fa-circle cyan'></i>` also replace the `c#` in `fc#`. So the `f` is leftover.

What would be the best solution? I think regex_replace would work but Im a completely regex beginner. Someone might have some useful tips or solutions?

Greetings

Comment: What are the diffrences between c# m# fc# and fm#??

Comment: Dont know if I get you right but the diffrences are just the values. m# stand for magenta fm# for lightmangenta and so on.

Comment: Oh sry. now I see. The class values are wrong ... my bad and fixed.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/yoHocN/1/ this works but the negative lookbehind `<!` give me an smarty error in my template.

Comment: Your smarty 'method' for replace will be too big, it's not better for you to do it in PHP and send the <i class ............. to the smarty file with php ?

Comment: ya it seems so ...

Comment: You can use this regex with smarty : `[^#]+#`

Comment: can u post a quick example at regex101.com, would be very nice ;)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/s90tMz/1

Comment: ah ok u did it this way. U got all matches with one regex. My orginal plan with a working regex_replace was like this ...
`[{$oAttr->oxattribute__oxvalue->value|regex_replace:"(^|\b)m\b":"<i class='fas fa-circle magenta'></i>"|regex_replace:"(^|\b)c\b":"<i class='fas fa-circle cyan'></i>"|regex_replace:"(^|\b)y\b":"<i class='fas fa-circle yello'></i>"}]` and so on ... but with one regex and and multimatches im not sure how to handle this now for the html tags.